# parseFloat - change hours to hours & minutes

Tags: javascript, parsing

I have had some code developed by someone else which I am needing to edit and am struggling to work out.

The code is set to take an entered figure and return a calculation and output and return as time taken.

This is the code:

```
minutes = parseFloat((salary / $(this).data('per-year') * 525600));

        if(minutes < 60){

            time = format(parseFloat(minutes),0);

            if(time < 2) time_label = 'minute';
            else time_label = 'minutes';    

        }else if(minutes >= 60 && minutes < (60 * 24)){
            time = format(parseFloat((minutes / 60)),1); 

            if(time < 2) time_label = 'hour';
            else time_label = 'hours';  

        }else{
            time = format(parseFloat((minutes / (24 * 60))),1); 

            if(time < 2) time_label = 'day';
            else time_label = 'days';   

        } 

        $(this).find('.time').html(time_label); 

        time = time.replace(/(\.[0-9]*?)0+$/, "$1");
        time = time.replace(/\.$/, ""); 

        $(this).find('.stat-minute').html(time); 

    });
```

At the moment this would display as say '4.6 hours'.

I want this to display as 4 hours 36 minutes.

Is there an easy way to do this based on the code above?

Any assistance is appreciated!

Comment: just multiplate the 0,6*60 and you'll get 36!

Comment: but I'd recommend to rewrite the code to use DateTime. seems so much easier.